# gradle apply from: not using parent script directory

Tags: gradle, apply, relative-path

/path/script

```
foo.gradle
    apply from: 'bar.gradle'

bar.gradle
```

/path/work

```
build.gradle
   apply from: '/path/script/foo.gradle'
```

Error:  bar.gradle is not found.

Gradle is looking for it in the current working dir /path/work. It should resolve the relative path based on the directory of its parent script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it shouldn't resolve the relative path based on the directory of its parent script, because that's not what specified in [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginAware.html#apply(java.util.Map)):

> - from: A script to apply. Accepts any path supported by [`Project.uri(Object)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#uri(java.lang.Object)).

... and, following the above link, ...

> Resolves a file path to a URI, relative to the project directory of this project.

Since the `Project` scope is applied to the script, applying another script file from the there is the same as applying it from the original script.